# Show that the line integral is independent of path and evaluate the integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

The problem:

> **19-20** Show that the line integral is independent of path and evaluate the integral.
>
> **19.** $\int_C 2xe^{-y}dx + (2y - x^2e^{-y})dy$,
>
> C is any path from $(1,0)$ to $(2,1)$

I was able to find $f(x,y)$ and show $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are the parts inside the integrals, but when i tried taking the integrals with (2,1) as my upper bound and (1,0) as my lower bound, I kept getting 7/e, but the answer is 4/e. Can someone show me how they get 4/e? I'm afraid this isn't a mere calculation error, but something I'm not understanding correctly.

Comment: What do you think  the potential $f(x,y)$ is?

Comment: $x^2e^(-y) + y^2$ I'm not sure why my power is coming up weird, its supposed to be e raised to the negative y

Comment: OK, that's good.  Let me check then...

Comment: It's definitely $4/e$.

Comment: You can write `$e^{-y}$` to display $e^{-y}$.

Comment: Why don’t you show us how you get $7/e$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x,y) = x^2e^{-y} + y^2$ is a valid potential.  Let's use it:
$$
x^2e^{-y} + y^2 \Bigr|_{(1,0)}^{(2,1)} = (4e^{-1} + 1) - (1+0) = \frac{4}{e}.
$$

Comment: oohhhh I was evaluating the integral above with those values instead of evaluating the function f(x,y)

Comment: That's the kind of mistake everyone makes once, then never forgets, and never makes it again.

Comment: ............ :)